# Any assets manager on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-management

Does anybody know any asset manager on rails 3 for upload/browse image/file? Like this one http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php

Answer (score 0):

I once looked quite a bit for something similar and never really found anything remotely complete.

I got a few ideas from https://github.com/vinyll/rails-mediabrowser but unfortunately that looks unmaintained.

Comment: I got the following stacktrace, after install it as plugin: Started GET "/mediabrowser" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-15 09:22:26 +0400
  Processing by MediabrowserController#list as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "/uploads":String):

Comment: Yeah, I added that issue a while back. You can see the fix here: https://github.com/vinyll/rails-mediabrowser/issues/1